# Convert seconds into hours in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-conversion

I have tried to countdown hours in Swift, however that returned the input in seconds. I would like to return the input in hours. How can I convert the seconds to hours?

Please see my code below:

```
var remainingTime: NSTimeInterval = 0
var endDate: NSDate!
var timer = NSTimer()
var timerCounter:NSTimeInterval!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    remainingTime = 7200.0   //--> Here I Want to give input in hours like 2 hours or 3 hours not in seconds.

    let (h,m,s) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(7200)
    print ("\(h) Hours")

    endDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(remainingTime)   // set your future end date by adding the time for your timer

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "updateLabel", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)  // create a timer to update your label

}

func updateLabel()
{
    timerlbl.text = endDate.timeIntervalSinceNow.hmmss
}

func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
}
```

Comment: Divide/multiply by 3600?

Comment: I do that in function after give the input as 7200 seconds,but i want to give input as like 2 hour or 3 hour...@jtbandes

Comment: Hi, you can find library here for NSDate extensions : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816141/convert-seconds-into-hours-in-ios-swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816141/convert-seconds-into-hours-in-ios-swift)

Comment: (seconds/3600), ((seconds/60) % 60), (seconds% 60)

Comment: Thanks its working..@LeoDabus

Comment: @Saravanakumar you are welcome